# Computing the resolvent of A given the inverse of A

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

I have a matrix $A$ for which I also know (each element of) its inverse $A^{-1}$. Knowing this information, is it possible to write down a closed formula for its resolvent $(A-tI)^{-1}$?

I know this is possible when $t $ is larger than the spectral radius of $A$ using the Neumann series and without using the inverse. But what about general values of $t$?

I'm interested particulalry in the case when $A$ is not Hermitian.

Comment: Maybe the Sherman Woodbury formula is also of interest for you.

Comment: But still - this is not a nice formula. If such formula existed, spectral theory would be trivial - which it is absolutely not. But you can at least derive one for $2\times 2$.

Comment: For small $t$, you could also use the Neumann series. If $t$ is sufficiently small, you could use a linear approximation.

Comment: What guarantees that the Neumann series will converge in the case of small $t$?

Comment: $(A-tI)^{-1}=A^{-1}(I-tA^{-1})^{-1}=A^{-1}\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}t^nA^{-n}$

Comment: Thanks @DisintegratingByParts